# Generic Method public T Method() where T : BaseViewModel always returns NULL

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am having a brain-fart at the moment.  I am trying to have a BaseController for all my controllers.  With that, I want to have a method to create the various ViewModels for the Views that all inherit from a BaseViewModel and set properties that are in the BaseViewModel. The properties in the BaseViewModel are set depending on which controller action is being used so I cannot just set them in the BaseViewModel constructor.

However, I keep getting a Null value returned when I call it.

Here is the method in the BaseController:

```
/// <summary>
/// Instantiate a ViewModel
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">ViewModel that inherits <see cref="BaseViewModel"/></typeparam>
/// <returns></returns>
public T SetupViewModel<T>(int? currentTrack = null) where T : BaseViewModel
{
     // Return a new instance of a ViewModel
    return new BaseViewModel(_Context)
    {
         // Set the current track
         CurrentTrack = currentTrack,
    } as T;
}
```

I call it like this in public class HomeController : BaseController:

```
/// <summary>
/// Main page
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // Instantiate the view model
    var vm = SetupViewModel<HomeViewModel>();
 
    // Setup the repositories
    vm.SetupRepositories();

    // Load the tables base on the user
    vm.Load(GetLoggedInUserName());

    // Return the view with model
    return View(vm);
}
```

When I break at vm.SetupRepositories(), the variable vm is NULL.

**EDIT** (response to comments about new()
I get this when I try the new()

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does your HomeViewModel inherited from BaseViewModel?

Comment: You are creating object of BaseViewModel not the object of T. You can not cast BaseViewModel object to T object, that's why you are getting it null.

Comment: The `SetupViewModel()` method is creating a `BaseViewModel` instance but upon `return` it refers to it as `T`, which in this case is `HomeViewModel`. Since the casting fails, it returns `null`.

What I expected your method to do is to call `new T()` and enable it by adding another generic constraint: `where T : BaseViewModel, new()`

Comment: @Nenad Yes; Chentan, I have tried return new T(_Context) but that doesn't compile.  I thought it would since I am saying T has to inherit BaseViewModel which has that in it's constructor.

Comment: @haim770, see my edit with photo.

Comment: @Red_Phoenix, You can't pass a parameter to the constructor. The meaning of the `new()` constraint is: "The type has a *parameter-less* constructor". Try to pass the `_Context` as a property instead

Comment: Does CurrentTrack accept the null value from currentTrack, or does it have to be int default of 0?
I suppose if the whole object is null, you won't even be able to assign it, so it may not matter at all...

Comment: @haim770, that was it.  I have two constructors for BaseViewModel, a default one and one with the context as a parameter.  I changed it to a property setting and it took. Thanks.  If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as such.  I knew it had to be something simple I was overlooking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I thought, it was something small.  Thank you haim770 (comment for OP) for pointing the way.

My BaseViewModel has two constructors (a default and one that accepts the parameter to set the context.  So instead I just needed to set the context as a property and not through the parameter.  Also, instantiate a new T instead of the BVM.

```
/// <summary>
/// Instantiate a ViewModel
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">ViewModel that inherits <see cref="BaseViewModel"/></typeparam>
/// <returns></returns>
public T SetupViewModel<T>(int? currentTrack = null) where T : BaseViewModel, new()
{
     // Return a new instance of a ViewModel
    return new T()
    {
         // Set the Context
         Context = _Context,

         // Set the current track
         CurrentTrack = currentTrack,
    } as T;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, to answer the first part of your question, why is this null?

```
public T SetupViewModel<T>(int? currentTrack = null) where T : BaseViewModel

{
     // Return a new instance of a ViewModel
    return new BaseViewModel(_Context)
    {
         // Set the current track
         CurrentTrack = currentTrack,
    } as T;
}
```

Will return null unless your 'T' is BaseViewModel.  The `as` keyword will cast if possible, but if it cannot, will return null.  You have instantiated a BaseViewModel, but expect it to cast to (I assume) one of its subtypes 'T'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator

---

**How to fix it?**

I would suggest that you look again at the need for a base controller and consider what benefit you are hoping to get out of this method.

I would recommend that you find a few examples for dependency injection and set up your repositories using constructor injection.

Your concrete controllers will have to be responsible for setting up your view model mappings, unless you abstract this out further to some kind of factory.  Again, be sure you know what benefit you are trying to achieve by doing so - are all your controllers going to be sufficiently the same and simple enough to make this valid.  If not, consider an alternative approach.

I've found in the past that if a generic approach you are taking is distinctly hard to implement, it's usually a sign that there is an alternative architecture that is probably better.

**Composition vs inheritance**

Not to belabour the point too much, but in my experience, BaseViewModels and the BaseController type implementation tend to suffer from the "fragile base class" problem.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class#:~:text=The%20fragile%20base%20class%20problem,the%20derived%20classes%20to%20malfunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class#:%7E:text=The%20fragile%20base%20class%20problem,the%20derived%20classes%20to%20malfunction).

It would likely be better to do away with both of these base classes and instead have your viewmodels inherit from an interface containing your 'CurrenTrack' and compose the behaviour you need to create a view model into your controllers instead of trying to force it all through a single base class.

Base controllers tend to become collectors of cruft as projects move on and come become quite difficult to both fix and unit test.